# obd connection issues android

Tags: android, bluetooth, connect

I am trying to connect to an obi simulator, the torque app connects perfectly but i am not able to do it. I don't know if I need to check the protocols.

Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use UUID SPP for the connection and you must know that the Device Class for the OBD II adapters is 0x1f00 for Bluetooth Connections

Answer (score 0):

You should check the protocol before ordering a OBD tool. Some support OBD2, some fits CAN BUS protocol.